# Проблемы с роутером D-Link при автоматическом определении адреса

Tags: wifi

Есть у меня роутер D-Link.

Недавно мой Интернет-провайдер перешёл на автоматическое определение адреса. После этого периодически стал отрубаться DNS. На корпоративный портал по IP заходит без проблем, сайты по URL не находит. Сосед посоветовал перенастроиться на автоматическое определение адреса.

Зашёл в Web-интерфейс роутера по IP 192.168.0.1 и нажал на Radio-кнопку, напоминающую на автоматическое определение адреса. После нажатия на Submit роутер предложил перейти на какой-то другой IP. Интернет заработал, но ни на 192.168.0.1, ни на тот IP, который предложил Web-интерфейс роутера, зайти нельзя - тупо ждёт о отваливается по таймауту. Жесткие перезагружки и нажатие кнопки Reset на корпусе роутера ни к чему не привели.

Мало того. Интернет работает где-то полчаса, после чего вырубается. Если зайти в сетевые подключения и исправить подключение, то он восстанавливается. На полчаса.

Что случилось и как с этим быть?

Comment: А пробовали заходить по 192.168.1.1?
При этом ваш адрес должен быть из подсети 192.168.1.*

Comment: Попробовал. Не заходит <br><br> ipconfig выдаёт 10.30.2.56 для моей машины, 172.16.1.21 для DHCP-сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, заработало.

Для перезагрузки роутера кнопку перезагрузки надо не просто нажать, а держать 10 секунд. После этого всё подсоединилось.

Answer (score 2):

1. Надо определиться с тем, что есть внутренний интерфейс - LAN, для подключения своих ПК из внутренней сети, и есть WAN - для подключения к провайдеру. Соответствующим образом подключить шнуры.
2. Для внутренней сети ставим на роутер IP 192.168.1.1 и заранее известный пароль для доступа. Также отмечаем, что роутер должен выступать в роли DHCP-сервера, т.е. автоматически давать адреса компам из локальной сети. На компьютерах соответственно везде ставим автоматические настройки сети.
3. Смотрим, чтобы ПК корректно получали адреса. Если не получается - делаем статический адрес вида 192.168.1.x/255.255.255.0/gateway=192.168.1.1 и пробуем настроить DHCP дальше.
4. Теперь для WAN-интерфейса роутера ставим автоматическое получение адреса по DHCP. Т.е. роутер должен получать адрес от провайдера.
5. В качестве DNS я бы прописал в настройках роутера 8.8.8.8 и 8.8.4.4. Это OpenDNS от Google и роутер должен эти настройки передать на все компьютеры.
6. PROFIT!

PS: вообще д-линк ненавижу. У них нормального оборудования практически нет. Возьмите как минимум Zyxel/TP-Link

PPS: еще нюанс - если у провайдера в договоре прописан MAC-адрес оборудования, которое имеет доступ в интернет и этот MAC не совпадает с MAC'ом WAN-интерфейса роутера, то нужно в параметрах роутера MAC из договора вбить. Эта "фича" называется "клонированием мака"

Comment: >> Для внутренней сети ставим на роутер IP 192.168.1.1 <br><br> Каким образом? Меня как раз больше всего беспокоит тот факт, что я не могу туда зайти. На самом устройстве кнопок нет, чтобы выставить его IP.

Comment: Вся настройка через Web-интерфейс. Если роутер не отвечает - нужно сбросить аппаратным путем настройки. Обычно - выключить у-во, а затем включить с зажатой кнопкой сброса, пока не начнется индикация того, что настройки сбросились. Как правило, все интеллектуально понятно.